# how to add file path in to python script

Tags: python, extract, filepath, glob

I have got a script that delves into a given directory recursively, digs out all files that have a specific file name and puts the contents of all the ones it finds into a single file.

The script works as I need it to in terms of hunting the files and outputting all the contents to a single xml file. However I would like it to add in the file path as well so I know the location of each given file it has found. This is my code so far:

```
import glob

lines=[] #list
for inputfile in glob.glob('D:\path\to\scan\**\project_information.xml', recursive=True): 
    with open ('D:\path\result\output.xml', 'w') as out_file:
        with open (inputfile, "rt") as in_file:  
            print("<projectpath>", inputfile, file=out_file)
            for line in in_file: 
                lines.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
            for linenum, line in enumerate(lines):
                print(line, file=out_file)
```

Each project_information.xml the script looks for looks like the below:

```
<project>
<name>project1</name>
<Projection>UTM84-30N</Projection>
<Build>Jan 30 2015</Build>
</project>
```

Ideally for every entry that is found and subsequently added to my output I would like it write the file path within the  tag. (You may have guess this is an XML table to go in to Excel) for example -

```
<project>
**<filepath>C:\path\to\file\**
<name>project1</name>
<Projection>UTM84-30N</Projection>
<Build>Jan 30 2015</Build>
</project>
<project>
**<filepath>C:\path\to\file\blah\**
<name>project2</name>
<Projection>UTM84-30N</Projection>
<Build>Jan 30 2015</Build>
</project>
```

I thought adding a line after the with statement would do it but that only appears to print the first occurrence and not get in the loop - Not only that even if that did work, it wouldn't be within the  parent tag.

```
print("<projectpath>", inputfile, file=out_file)
```

Pretty new to python so any suggestions or changes to my crude code are very much appreciated!

############UPDATE

So as @olinox14 suggested I had a look at the lxml module and got it to add a new tag in with that.

```
tree = ET.parse(in_file)
root = tree.getroot()
    for child in root:
        folder = ET.SubElement(child, 'folder')
        folder.text = (in_file.name)
        tree.write('C:\\output\\output2.xml')
```

Comment: Two questions: 1) Did you consider using a library to handle XML files? (for example `lxml`)? This would take care of the formatting and serialization, letting you focus on the structure of the document you want to have. 2) why using `print(... file=out_file)` instead of `out_file.write()`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - both really boil down to a 'noob' approach of Python. I didn't know of lxml in python which i'll have a look at, as for the out file - again not really a conscious choice to avoid it, just wasn't aware of it. Is that a more efficient way to write the output?

Comment: I don't know if it's more efficient or not (although I expect `print` to eventually call `write` itself when running), but it's definitely more clear. In general, `print` is used to write on some terminal output (the standard value for `file` is stdout)

Comment: I would also suggest moving your write `with .. as out_file` loop outside the `for inputfile...` loop so it won't open in each loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many things here:

1. AsGPhilo said in the comments, consider using a dedicated library to handle XML files, most known is [lxml](https://lxml.de/).
2. You should permute your `for inputfile in...` and `with open(...) as out_file` to avoid opening/closing this file at each iteration
3. Do not use `print(..., file=...)` when you can use `out_file.write(...)`

A good start here, you could need to arrange it:

```
import glob
from lxml import etree

root = etree.Element("root")

with open ('D:\path\result\output.xml', 'w') as out_file:
    for inputfile in glob.glob('D:\path\to\scan\**\project_information.xml', recursive=True): 

        with open (inputfile, "r") as in_file:
            project = etree.SubElement(root, "project", path=in_file)
            # ... continue with your processing

    root.write(out_file, pretty_print=True)
```

Comment: Thanks olinox. I've installed the lxml module. Will have a wrestle with it and see how i get on.

Comment: Thanks Olinox, updated my question with the answer as was having a mare posting the code in the comment box.